# What artefacts are made from Mithril?

Tags: the-lord-of-the-rings, tolkiens-legendarium, mithril

[This question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/141645/46509)  got me thinking, in *The Hobbit* we see Bilbo receive a mithril shirt, which he gives to Frodo in *The Lord of the Rings*.

**Are any there any other weapons or armour that we know are made of Mithril?**

Comment: The west doors of Moria were made by Celebrimbor with Mithril.

Comment: [Objects made of Mithril](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mithril#Other_mithril_objects_in_Tolkien.27s_writings) - Wikipedia

Comment: [Objects made of Mithril](http://lotr.wikia.com/wiki/Mithril#Other_Mithril_objects_in_the_Lord_of_the_Rings_novels) - One Ring Wiki

Comment: @Valorum Wikipedia shouldn't be so complete...

Comment: @Ginasius You're talking about nerds on the internet and LOTR. Of course it's complete.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In addition to Bilbo's mithril chain shirt, we know of:

- Nenya, the Ring of Power borne by Galadriel:

  > On her finger was Nenya, the ring wrought of mithril, that bore a single white stone flickering like a frosty star.
  >
  > <sup>*Return of the King* Book VI Chapter 9: "The Grey Havens"</sup>
- The substance *ithildin*:

  > *Mithril*! All folk desired it. It could be beaten like copper, and polished like glass; and the Dwarves could make of it a metal, light and yet harder than tempered steel. Its beauty was like to that of common silver, but the beauty of *mithril* did not tarnish or grow dim. The Elves dearly loved it, and among many uses they made of it *ithildin*, starmoon
  >
  > <sup>*Fellowship of the Ring* Book II Chapter 4: "A Journey in the Dark"</sup>

  The only known use of *ithildin* was the West-gate of Moria:

  > At the top, as high as Gandalf could reach, was an arch of interlacing letters in an Elvish character. Below, though the threads were in places blurred or broken, the outline could be seen of an anvil and a hammer surmounted by a crown with seven stars. Beneath these again were two trees, each bearing crescent moons. More clearly than all else there shone forth in the middle of the door a single star with many rays.
  >
  > *[...]*
  >
  > 'They are wrought of *ithildin* that mirrors only starlight and moonlight, and sleeps until it is touched by one who speaks words now long forgotten in Middle-earth.
  >
  > <sup>*Fellowship of the Ring* Book II Chapter 4: "A Journey in the Dark"</sup>

  It's also implied that the Elves did a bunch of other things with *mithril*, but we have no explicit references to what those might be.
- Presumably the Elves used *ithildin* in other places than the one door, but we have no explicit confirmation. It seems likely that the Moon-letters of the Dwarves were made of a substance not unlike *ithildin*, since they exhibit similar characteristics:

  > "Moon-letters are rune-letters, but you cannot see them," said Elrond, "not when you look straight at them. They can only be seen when the moon shines behind them
  >
  > <sup>*The Hobbit* Chapter 3: "A Short Rest"</sup>
- The original Elendilmir was set in a filet of *mithril*:

  > [T]he Elendilmir itself, the white star of Elvish crystal upon a fillet of *mithril* that had descended from Silmarien to Elendil, and had been taken by him as the token of royalty in the North Kingdom.
  >
  > <sup>*Unfinished Tales* Part 3: "The Third Age" Chapter 1: "The Disaster at the Gladden Fields"</sup>

  It's possible that the second Elendilmir, the one wrought for Valandil after the first was lost with Isildur, was also made from *mithril*; however, I've yet to find evidence of this.
- The helmets of the Citadel guard:

  > The Guards of the gate were robed in black, and their helms were of strange shape, high-crowned, with long cheek-guards close-fitting to the face, and above the cheek-guards were set the white wings of sea-birds; but the helms gleamed with a flame of silver, for they were indeed wrought of *mithril*, heirlooms from the glory of old days.
  >
  > <sup>*Return of the King* Book V Chapter 1: "Minas Tirith"</sup>
- The crown on Aragorn's standard:

  > Upon the foremost ship a great standard broke, and the wind displayed it as she turned towards the Harlond. There flowered a White Tree, and that was for Gondor; but Seven Stars were about it, and a high crown above it, the signs of Elendil that no lord had borne for years beyond count. And the stars flamed in the sunlight, for they were wrought of gems by Arwen daughter of Elrond; and the crown was bright in the morning, for it was wrought of *mithril* and gold.
  >
  > <sup>*Return of the King* Book V Chapter 6: "The Battle of the Pelennor Fields"</sup>
- In the Fourth Age, Gimli forged new gates for Minas Tirith:

  > After the fall of Sauron, Gimli brought south a part of the Dwarf-folk of
  >   Erebor, and he became Lord of the Glittering Caves. He and his people did great
  >   works in Gondor and Rohan. For Minas Tirith they forged gates of *mithril* and
  >   steel to replace those broken by the Witch-king.
  >
  > <sup>*Return of the King* Appendix A: "Annals of the Kings and Rulers" III Durin's Folk</sup>
- It's likely that more heirlooms of Númenor were made of *mithril* before the Downfall; *Unfinished Tales* remarks of Tar-Telemmaitë, fifteenth king of Númenor:

  > This King was so called<sup>1</sup> because of his love of silver, and he bade his servants to seek ever for *mithril*.
  >
  > <sup>*Unfinished Tales* Part 2: "The Second Age" Chapter 3: "The Line of Elros: Kings of Númenor"</sup>

  Though, in fairness, we don't know whether he made anything of it or just hoarded the raw metal.

---

<sup>1</sup> Per the Index of *Unfinished Tales*, *telemmaitë* means "silver-handed" in Quenya

Comment: And the [Mariner's ship](http://www.glyphweb.com/arda/e/earendil.html), at least according to Bilbo - "*A ship then new they built for him of mithril and of elven-glass with shining prow; no shaven oar nor sail she bore on silver mast:"*

Comment: I'll note here that, although [Wikipedia claims](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mithril#Other_mithril_objects_in_Tolkien.27s_writings) that Eärendil was given a ship made from *mithril* for his new life as a star, the only source for this is Bilbo's poem; the actual stories about Eärendil I've looked at so far indicate that he set sail again in Vingilot, which was not made from *mithril* (cc @Valorum)